# PowerShell script to download PBIX without prompt

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I am using below code to auto export PBIX from workspace:

```
Login-PowerBIServiceAccount 
Export-PowerBIReport -WorkspaceId xyz-abc-pqr-lmn-rtp -Id ewrew-werwe-sd-sss-ssssss -OutFile .\abc.pbix
```

It does exports the PBIX but prompts a dialogue box, where I have to confirm my user name. I want to get rid of this dialogue box as this is going to be an automated utility. I tried below:

```
$password = 'password' | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = 'abc@pqr.com'
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $credential
```

However above code, gives me below issue:

```
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount : Failed to get ADAL token: Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred
```

Any clue on this.

Comment: What happens if you do it interactively instead: `Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential (Get-Credential)` Things to consider: is the account MFA-enabled? Are you accessing the internet via a proxy?

Comment: Yes! The account is MFA enabled. The code given by you does asks for an username and password but it fails to authenticate and gives error ` Login-PowerBIServiceAccount : Failed to get ADAL token ` I am not accessing the internet via proxy.

Comment: How do I make it work with all these considerations?

Comment: Ok, if it's the MFA, maybe add the account to the conditional access policy bypass and/or the IP you're running it from. And/or If you're using an account that's got high privileges like GA permanently assigned (bad practice!), use an account that just has the privileges needed instead. And maybe do your own searches for working around MFA for PowerBI reporting or best practices re rights for reporting accounts (I don't know anything about Power BI personally)

Comment: In fact I just did that. Looks like the [module doesn't support mfa](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-powershell/issues/135). And here's a page that discusses a [related  problem](https://gotoguy.blog/2016/09/09/how-to-enable-azure-mfa-for-online-powershell-modules-that-dont-support-mfa/?ampcf=) and a workaround (which fits my suggestion